# Javascript AJAX PHP if statement not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've been struggling with this problem for over two hours now and can find any reasonable solution. If i will get rid of if statement marked by ---> this arrow.  alert() on its on will work. It will will be triggered when i just put if(true) but it don't work with following condition. I'm not really good with this languages. Just have to finish that for school project. I'm sure it is something small but cat figure it out on my own.

```
   Java Script Function

   function checkLogin(str) {


       if (str.length == 0) {

           return;
       } else {

           var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
               if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                   var ret = xmlhttp.responseText;

           ---->    if (ret == "match"){
                        alert("Login name already exists !");
                    }
                }
           }
           xmlhttp.open("GET", "loginCheck.php?q=" + str, true);
           xmlhttp.send();
       }
   } 

   PHP Code
   /*
   <?php
       include 'db.inc.php';
       date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

       $login = $_REQUEST["q"];


       $sql = "SELECT * FROM staffMembers";

        if (!($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql))){
           die ('An Error ->' . mysqli_error() );

       }



           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
               $firstName = $row['nameLogin'];
               $ret="true";
               if($firstName == $login){
                   $ret = "match";
                   break;
               }
           }
       mysqli_close($con);  


       echo $ret;
   ?>
   */
```

Comment: It probably means that the server does not return `match`. Outside of that `if` statement, try `alert(ret);`. What do you get?

Comment: done any basic debugging? `console.log(ret)` and see what's really coming back. Note that JS doesn't understand html, or anything your server spits out. It'll take ANY output and put it into `ret`, so if your code happens to issue a PHP warning, that warning becomes part of `ret`.

Comment: I will try to debug next time. I'm still very green . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code has possibly output whitespace around `match`. Try this

```
if (ret.trim() == "match"){
```

Comment: Other thing is that i wanted to follow this by document.getElementById().innerHTML = "" to clear out field in html, but it doesn't work too ??